# Hiding CONNECT requests in Charles Proxy

Tags: proxy

I get a lots of noise when using Charles including requests from background processes, browser extensions, and webpages open in inactive tabs in Chrome. Most of these requests come in the form of HTTP CONNECT requests.

How can I hide all of these CONNECT requests?